# MySQL: Use a select statement for stored procedure parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, subquery

I have a stored procedure that works:

```
call my_procedure('A,B,C,D');
```

I want to populate the A,B,C with a list from a subquery of another table, eg:

```
call my_procedure(
  SELECT group_concat(letters) FROM table WHERE type = 'some_type')
);
```

Possible? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT my_function(group_concat(letters)) FROM table WHERE type = 'some_type';
```

Comment: I updated the question to reflect it is actually a procedure that is fairly complex... and I don't think you can call procedures from a select... Sorry for the misrepresentation of my question.+1 for answering the original question.

Comment: as soon as I get enough rep ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the value to a user-defined variable and then pass that variable to the function.

For example:

```
SELECT group_concat(letters) 
INTO @foo
FROM table 
WHERE type = 'some_type';

call my_function(@foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass a string to a procedure that's returned as the result of subquery.

But not as a bare query:

```
mysql> create procedure foo (in s text) begin select s; end !!

mysql> call foo( select group_concat(user) from mysql.user );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'select group_concat(user) from mysql.user )' at line 1
```

If you enclose the query in parentheses, it counts as a *scalar subquery*, that is, a subquery that is bound to return one row, one column:

```
mysql> call foo( (select group_concat(user) from mysql.user) );
+--------------------+
| s                  |
+--------------------+
| root,root,bill,xbm |
+--------------------+
```